# Complexity of LSB and MSB of Diffie-Hellman

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Given generator $g$ of multiplicative cyclic group modulo $p$ a prime and two elements $h_1$ and $h_2$ such that there are $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively satisfying $g^{x_i}=h_i\bmod p$ at every $i\in\{1,2\}$, the Discrete Logarithm problem is to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ while the Diffie Hellman problem is to find $g^{x_1x_2}\bmod p$. Both these problems do not have polynomial in $\log p$ time algorithm.

What is the complexity of LSB and MSB of $g^{x_1x_2}\bmod p$? Is it related to or complete in any complexity class? I believe it should be in at most $UP$.

Comment: This problem is at least as hard as the decisional version of DH which asks to distinguish $g^{x_1x_2}$ from $g^z$ for a random $z$. If you could compute the first bit of $g^{x_1x_2}$, you could distinguish both with probability $\frac 12$.

Comment: The problem appears related to the notion of hard-core predicate. A quick [search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Hard%2Dcore%20predicate%20for%20diffie%20hellman&btnG=Search&as_sdt=800000000001&as_sdtp=on) reveals many papers that may contain answers.

Comment: @lamontap Is this true for LSB as well?

Comment: Yes, this should hold for any bit of $g^{x_1x_2}$. Although note that decisional DH is thought to be easier than computation/search DH in certain groups. For a reference, see Section 9.3.2 of [this textbook](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/imc.html).